# Can you customise the "hot questions" feed in the sidebar

Tags: feature-request, hot-questions

As well as the SE sites that I visit regularly, there are some SE sites that I have a passing interest in, but no expertise. So will never post answers but still enjoy reading interesting questions - Aviation, for example, I'll never join, but love seeing some of the behind the scenes stuff that you can learn there.

Others I can weigh in on an answer from time to time, but they're not my core interest. So its good when a question catches my eye while I'm on another SE site.

But then there are sites that I have zero interest in. Never have, never will. Sometimes the feed is full of questions from them, and contains nothing that would remotely interest me. Would it be possible to weed them out of my hot questions feed?